# Initializing arrays in struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So I decided to write my own Big Integer library for a microcontoller in C (the PIC32 if that matters), but I'm having a weird problem that I don't understand.  When the code is run, the `big_int_t` structs `a` and `b` are at different memory locations, but `a->bytes` and `b->bytes` appear to be at the same location (confirmed by printing their pointers). Setting a value in `b->bytes` also changes the value in `a->bytes`.  In the main function below, printing the first element from either struct's `bytes` array shows `41`.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t size;
  uint8_t *bytes;
} big_int_t;

void big_init(big_int_t *big, uint8_t size) {
  big->size = size;
  uint8_t bytes[size];
  big->bytes = bytes;
  uint8_t i;
  for(i=0;i<big->size;i++) big->bytes[i] = 0;
}

int main() {
  big_int_t a,b;
  big_init(&a,1);
  big_init(&b,1);
  a.bytes[0] = 16;
  b.bytes[0] = 41;
  printf("%d\n",a.bytes[0]);
  printf("%d\n",b.bytes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Use `malloc` to get memory for `bytes`. Do not use stack variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `big_init` the variable `bytes` is a *local* Variable, one that will go out of scope and disappear once the function returns. The pointer stored in `big->bytes` will become a stray pointer when the function returns, and dereferencing the pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can't use a local array for this, instead you need to allocate the array dynamically with `malloc`:

```
big->bytes = malloc(sizeof(*big->bytes) * big->size);
```

But don't forget to `free` the memory once you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating your byte buffer on the stack:

```
uint8_t bytes[size];
```

When big_init exits the buffer is no longer valid. It will get randomly overwritten.

You probably want to dynamically allocate it using `malloc()`, but then you have to be careful to free it up again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour is that you are assigning `bytes` with a pointer on the **stack**. When calling `big_init` for the first time, the local variable `bytes` will be placed on the stack and it's address will be used for `bytes` in the struct. Afterwards, you are calling the function `big_init` **again**. Now, the same stack **as before** is build up, and the local variable `bytes` is placed on the **same location** as before. Therefore, the two assignments lead to the **same pointer**.